# Trying to link Eulerian and Lagrangian perturbations

Tags: fluid-dynamics, astrophysics

I'm trying to make sense of the link between a (linear) Eulerian (i.e., at a given point) and Lagrangian (following a fluid element) perturbation. I will here express not only where I'm stuck, but also my current understanding of the topic, so I beg that if you find any misconception, please point it out!

**>> Background**

So far, I (think I) know that in the **Eulerian** perturbation, if $h(\boldsymbol{r},t)$ is the perturbed quantity, where $\boldsymbol{r}=\boldsymbol{r}_0+\boldsymbol{\delta r}$ is the new position vector and $\boldsymbol{\delta r}$ is a small displacement around $\boldsymbol{r}_0$, then
$$h(\boldsymbol{r},t)=h_0(\boldsymbol{r})+h'(\boldsymbol{r},t),\ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ (1)$$
where $h_0(\boldsymbol{r})$ is the quantity at an equilibrium state evaluated at $\boldsymbol{r}$ and $h'(\boldsymbol{r},t)$ is a small perturbation.

On the other hand, the **Lagrangian** perturbation $\delta h(\boldsymbol{r})$ can be written as
$$\delta h(\boldsymbol{r})=h(\boldsymbol{r}_0+\boldsymbol{\delta r})-h_0(\boldsymbol{r}_0)=\left[h(\boldsymbol{r}_0)+\boldsymbol{\delta r}\cdot \nabla h_0(\boldsymbol{r}_0)\right]-h_0(\boldsymbol{r})$$
or, by using the relation found for the Eulerian perturbation, eq. $(1)$, evaluated at $\boldsymbol{r}_0$,
$$\delta h(\boldsymbol{r})=h'(\boldsymbol{r}_0)+\boldsymbol{\delta r}\cdot \nabla h_0(\boldsymbol{r}_0).$$

**>> The question**

What I have trouble relating is $\delta h(\boldsymbol{r})$ and $h'(\boldsymbol{r},t)$. Both are small perturbations but, in this case, there is a explicit dependance on $\boldsymbol{r}_0$ by $\delta h(\boldsymbol{r})$. However, if I fix $\boldsymbol{r}_0$, both represent a perturbation about that point so...why are they different? My intuition (probably messed up by know; thanks QM) tells me that they are equal, but the notation is different in almost every book I've read on the topic. Can anyone shine some light here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Eulerian description is a map from a point in real space $x$  (indexes suppressed) and the fluid label $\Phi$ that is found in $x$ at the time $t$, namely $(t,x)\rightarrow (t,\Phi(t,x))$. The physical observables are, typically, functions of $\Phi$ and its derivatives $\partial\Phi$(unless there are external sources), such as $h=h(\Phi,\partial\Phi)$. This corresponds to a standard field theory approach.
Vice versa,the Lagrangian description is the inverse map, at any time, from a fluid element labeled by $\Phi$ to its position in real space $x(t)$, namely $(t,\Phi)\rightarrow (t,x(t,\Phi))$. 
Relating the two descriptions is just matter of changing the variables, e.g. $h(\Phi)$ becomes $\tilde{h}(t,x)=h(\Phi(t,x))$ when passing to the Lagrangian formulation (assuming that $h$ is a scalar quantity). With a slightly abuse of notation, it's customary  not to include the \tilde above.

Back to your original example in perturbation theory: when you say $x_0+\delta x$ in the lagrangian formulation you are actually referring to some fluid element $\Phi_0$ which is not found in $x_0$ anymore but rather in $x(t,\Phi_0)=x_0(t,\Phi_0)+\delta x(t,\Phi_0)$.  I can also read it saying that in the point $x_0$ I find a new fluid element, that is $\Phi_0+\delta\Phi$ (Eulerian description). By consistency of these two descriptions, I.e. $(\Phi_0+\delta\Phi)(t,x_0+\delta x)=\Phi_0(t,x_0)$, we get
$$\delta\Phi=-\left.\frac{\partial \Phi^i}{\partial x^j}\right|_{x_0}\delta x^j\,.$$
Now, imagine you are interested in some physical quantity $\tilde h(t,x)=h(t,\Phi(t,x))$. The perturbation thus reads
$$
\delta \tilde{h}=-\left.\frac{\partial h}{\partial \Phi^i}\right|_{\Phi_0}\left.\frac{\partial \Phi^i}{\partial x^j}\right|_{x_0}\delta x^j\,.
$$

Comment: Can you explain, physically, the difference? I see the mathematical one; is the physical one I don't get.

Comment: @argopulos Please register your account, you will be able to edit and comment on your posts without hassle.

Comment: @nestor: I've  tried to make more clear what the perturbations are by re-editing my answer. There is no physical difference, it's just about what coordinates you like more.